# Express Migration tool truncating the Core database tables

Tags: upgrade, express-migration-tool

While running the express migration tool to migrate application from Sitecore 7.2 to 8.2, the users available in ASPNET_Users is getting truncated to just only to 4 records instead of 10K records. This has created a big issue and looking for option to retain so as these records can be retained while running the tool.

Comment: try to run the tool again using a CLEAN new express migration tool, but this time only select the security option.